# Resizing the container, the two grey squares should grow as much as possible, constrained by the diagonal.. easy way to do it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, math, trigonometry

Here's what I did: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BEV6W/)

```
$("#container").resizable({
    resize: function (event, ui) {
        var w = ui.size.width;
        var h = ui.size.height;
        var l;
        if (w>h) l = h/2;
        else l = w/2
        $("#left").width(l).height(l);
        $("#right").width(l).height(l);
    }
})
```

As you can see, I just set the side of the squares to half the min between width and height of the container. This only works if the container itself is square.

What I would like is for the squares to grow as much as possible, without getting on the other side of the diagonal and maintaining the squared proportion, for any container size.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take the line that goes through the diagonal of the square and search for the intersection with the diagonal of the rectangle, you'll find the point that the square will have to reach. You can use the distance between this point and the origin to compute the length of the diagonal of the squares and trivially get the side.

```
$("#container").resizable({
    resize: function (event, ui) {
        var w = ui.size.width;
        var h = ui.size.height;
        var m = h/w;
        var c = -h;

        var x = c/(-1-m);
        var y = -1*(c/(-1-m));

        var diag = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x,2) + Math.pow(y,2));
        var l = diag/Math.sqrt(2);
        $("#left").width(l).height(l);
        $("#right").width(l).height(l);
    }
})
```